# operator << for QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt

I override operator<<

```
QTextStream &operator<<(QTextStream &out, const QPair<quint8, qint32>& pair)
{
    out << QString("QPair<%1, %2> ").arg(QString::number(pair.first))
           .arg(QString::number(pair.second));
    return out;
}
```

How can I made template for this operation for different types of QPair
like: QPair<quint8, quint8> and so on.
Thanks!

Comment: Side note: There are overloads of `arg` function accepting arithmetic types, too, so no need to explicitly convert to string before via `number` function.

Comment: I'd prefer `out << "QPair<" << pair.first << ", " pair.second << '>'` – this makes it easier in the desired template function to cover *any* types in the pair, as you only need to overload `operator<<` for types that aren't supported yet. And you should leave adding the space afterwards to the user (so not inside this function).

Comment: @Aconcagua I don't actually use Qt myself so my answer is theoretical. Would you mind taking a look and tell me if it does what OP wants?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'd have interpreted the question the same way as you did (actually you've just been faster in writing than me...). Your template does so, but would work for numeric types only, as `number` function only accepts these. Just skipping these calls adds capability to accept `char`, `QChar`, `QString`, `QStringView` and `QLatin1String`. Any other type would have to be converted to any of the string related Qt classes before. For this purpose, see my second comment (alternatively cast operators might be added, but I'd prefer the stream operators).

Comment: @Aconcagua Aha, I see. Many thanks for taking a look. I made an edit. Not sure it catches all the cases you mentioned, but it should be a little more generic.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're welcome. But you need to split the format pattern as I did in my comment; `arg` function works similarly as `printf` does.

Comment: @Aconcagua The format pattern I leave up to OP to construct. I feel I've dug myself into a grave here since I don't know the framwork at all. :-) If you put up an answer, I'll upvote and delete mine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No need for, it's fine now ;)

Comment: @sid Did you try the templates in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make your function into a function template, replacing the hardcoded types with template parameters, like so:

```
template<class T, class U>
QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& out, const QPair<T, U>& pair) {
    out << QString("QPair<%1, %2> ")
               .arg(QString::number(pair.first))
               .arg(QString::number(pair.second));
    return out;
}
```

To make the template work for not only numeric Qt types, let the built-in `operator<<` overloads for the types do the work:

```
template<class T, class U>
QTextStream& operator<<(QTextStream& out, const QPair<T, U>& pair) {
    return out << "QPair<" << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << '>';
}
```